# how to pass dynamic/optional filter in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to select data from mongodb based on given filter. I am getting proper result if I pass static filter.

i.e.

```
var filter = {'categories ':'business'};
```

If I put dynamic values it is not showing up. I am able to see variable type as object and value is also correct.

```
static async getArticle(req, res, next) {
   try {

      var filter = {};
   if(req.body.categories || req.body.categories != "") {
       filter.categories = req.body.categories;
   }
   console.log('val: '+JSON.stringify(filter));
   console.log('org val: '+filter);
   console.log('obj type: '+typeof(filter));
   let totalArticle = await Models.Article.find(filter).count().exec();

  res.send({
       success: true,
       totalArticle: totalArticle
   });
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
       res.send({success: false, error});
   }
}
```

Output in console is

```
val: {"categories":"business"}
org val: [object Object]
obj type: object
```

If I pass static value as above I get following response.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "totalArticle": 2
}
```

and in console it is also same:

```
val: {"categories":"business"}
org val: [object Object]
obj type: object
```

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Aside from `categorie` rather than `categories`? Also try `console.log(req.body)` and make sure that what you are sending through is actually wht you expect.

Comment: @NeilLunn, here `categorie` is my table column name and  `categories` is variable name

Comment: So what did I just say to you as well?? Check the "inputs". If nothing returns you A. Have the wrong field names B. Have the wrong values C. Looking in the wrong collection/database. Those are the possible reasons. So one of those is what you are "doing wrong". Log your variables and find out which.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry about the typo. I have fixed the type in question. A I have the correct field. B. Correct value which is also in database. Hardcode/static variable gives me proper result. C. Looking in the right collection/database. Already checked everything by logging

Comment: Really? Because we can't see a thing here. Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not sitting at your desk. So unless you show us everything ( this is the console.log() output of `req.body`, this is a document in the collection, this is the collection name, etc.... ) then we don't know what your problem could be and cannot fix it for you. You have to share!

Comment: @NeilLunnte As per your suggestion, I have updated question with values I am getting in console and in response.

Comment: And the "Schema" for you mongoose model and the document? Again, I still cannot see your screen from here. Add `mongoose.set('debug',true)` to your listing somewhere around the `.connect()` statement so you can actually see the query being issued. This smacks all over of differently named fields being stripped from the query being issued.

Comment: Try to count the number of documents directly in your query: `Models.Article.count(filter).exec();`

Comment: @YouneL it's doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an error because you are setting "filter1" instead of "filter" in :

```
   let totalArticle = await Models.Article.find(filter1).count().exec();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My bad. I had type in writing question. It is not the case. I have updated the question. Pliss to review it

Comment: And what is the result of console.log(filter) just before your Mongo query ?

Comment: [object object]. If I do JSON.stringify it gives me proper object having perfect values.

Comment: Maybe you have to stringify your req.body.categories like this "filter.categories = JSON.stringify(req.body.categories);" ?

Comment: JSON.stringify is not solving an issue

Answer (score 0):

i use `$and` in filter object. so, my query fire in database `select * from collection_name where categorie like "%business"`

```
 var filter1 = {$and: []};
    if(req.body.categories) {
          var cat = new RegExp(req.body.categories);
          filter1.$and.push({categorie: cat});
    }
    let totalArticle = await Models.Article.find(filter1).count().exec();
    res.send({
          success: true,
          totalArticle: totalArticle
    });
```